# Username() in infopath form return empty string on sharepoint workflow form

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, form

I have an infopath form loaded as an initiation/association form for a sharepoint workflow.
I added a text field wich I want to be prefilled with the current user username. I'm using username() to get this. 
The problem is that it works great when I preview it in infopath, but once I deploy it to sharepoint the field is always empty.

I tried both setting username() as a default value for the field and with a rules on form load that sets the field value to username(). Neither works.

If I replace username() with any string (like "ciao"). the value is correctly set.

Any idea on how to get this working?

Comment: What kind of authentication is your sharepoint farm using ?

Comment: basic windows authentication

Comment: I had a similar issue, but i had issues with the function being case sensitive - userName()

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem and added additional idle call to username(); before assigning a value and it started to work (I used the call twice). If I deleted the idle call, the next username returned the null value. When I added it again, it worked fine. I didn't find a root of the problem, but now it works well with the idle call.

Comment: Was it in browser but not filler/client for, I wonder? Have you tried to enable always in Text box properties > Browser Forms (tab) > Postback Settings?